# Starting with Node.js...problems integrating Express

Tags: node.js

As mentioned, i'm trying to get up to speed on Node.js.  The following code seems to work just fine (except the 'site' does not seem to be recognized for some reason)...however the rest is functional:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');


var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
var params = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.url).query);
var MyURL = url.parse(req.url).search;  //example returns "?year=2017&month=february" 
var site = url.parse(req.url).host;  //example returns "localhost:8080"

res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
if ('lat' in params && 'lng' in params){
res.write('Coordinates passed ' + params['lat'] + ' ' + params['lng']);
console.log(MyURL);
res.write('Page Default: ' + site);
console.log('Page default ' + site);
}
else {
res.write('Coordinates not passed');
}

res.end();
});
server.listen(8080)
```

...However when I add the Express module...my commands seem to be ignored...as given here:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
var params = querystring.parse(url.parse(req.url).query);
var MyURL = url.parse(req.url).search;  //example returns "?year=2017&month=february" 
var site = url.parse(req.url).host;  //example returns "localhost:8080"

res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
if ('lat' in params && 'lng' in params){
res.write('Coordinates passed ' + params['lat'] + ' ' + params['lng']);
console.log(MyURL);
res.write('Page Default: ' + site);
console.log('Page default ' + site);
}
else {
res.write('Coordinates not passed');
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.write('You are connected to a Test');

console.log('This is a test...!');

});

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
var page = url.parse(req.url).pathname;  //example returns "index.html"

res.write('You are connected to the index.html page on this test site!');
res.write('Page Default: ' + page);
console.log(page);

});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.send(404, 'Page cannot be found!');
});

res.end();
});
server.listen(8080)
```

None of the "app." functions seem to be fired...can anybody explain what I'm not understanding here...?  I thank you in advance.  Regards...!

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you need to use app.listen instead of server.

[Look at the example here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I gave that a try...just changed the last line to 'app.listen(8080)'.  However now when I pass a URL I get a message "Cannot GET /index.html" (if I pass 'localhost:8080/index.html') or "Cannot GET /" (if I pass 'localhost:8080")...if I pass the full string with parameters I also get the "Cannot GET /index.html" printed in the browser window.

Comment: You need to use res.send() after res.write to actually send the data. Also if you want to point to a file as index.html, you should define the route and inside the function render the file with res.render('index.ejs')

Comment: Yes I will be adding in the ability to serve up an HTML file using 'res.render("index.ejs")' however right now i'm just trying to get the proper responses back in the browser window and the console so I know the server is responding to my URL posts.

Comment: I'm typing in URLs such as "http://localhost:8080" and "http://localhost:8080/index.html" and "http://localhost:8080/index.html?lat=14.620296&lng=121.055905" for example...to test to see if my code is functional.  The only part that is working is the last one, where I pass a URL with the 'lat and lng' parameters...the rest (which is written within the 'app.' statements) is not working at all, just being ignored it seems.

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps the 'http.createserver' and the server that is created by 'Express' are somehow interfering with each other...?   Possible?  I don't know just speculating here...the only part that works properly is the first part where I define the 'http.createserver'...after that nothing having to do with Express seems to be working at all.

Comment: It is possible since both are using the same port

Comment: So then it is not permitted to use both 'Express' and 'http' modules concurrently...???  One or the other only?  Does anybody know of a way to integrate the 'query' to test for the parameters ('lat' and 'lng' in my example) within Express?  It seems Express is very 'literal' (i.e. 'app.get('index.html')' or 'app.get('/')' or 'app.get('something here')'...), however as previously stated i'm still trying to learn this environment.

Comment: You can use postman or any other REST client to test your routes

Comment: Thanks...but is there some advantage to doing that?  I mean it is very easy just to type into the browser address bar.  In addition that doesn't solve this problem i'm having here...I will have to look at the Express documentation again...there may be built in functions specific to Express to be used for routes...other than the URL module...

Comment: I made a quick check and yes there does seem to be built-in 'middleware' routines that are used within Express for 'route' handling...it seems I will have to modify my code to use these functions rather than the 'http' and 'url' modules I had been using.